# How do I create a user registration Page in DotNetNuke 4.9.2

Tags: dotnetnuke, membership-provider, user-registration

I am looking for a way to create my own user registration page in DotNetNuke. I do not want to replace the default one, I just want to put dnn registration in a moduule I am building. Any insight on how to go about this would be great, I would like to use the current membership provider included with DotNetNuke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need to know is here, hope this helps someone else:

http://www.engagesoftware.com/Blog/EntryId/75/Membership-Provider-Video-Part-I.aspx

OK I want to share my code with everyone as this was a pain to figure out, but this will give an idea of what to do:

```
using DotNetNuke;
using DotNetNuke.Common;
using DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Users;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Actions;
using DotNetNuke.Security;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Localization;
using DotNetNuke.Security.Membership;




namespace DotNetNuke.Modules.Promotions
{
    /// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// The ViewPromotions class displays the content
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// </remarks>
    /// <history>
    /// </history>
    /// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    partial class View : PortalModuleBase, IActionable
    {
 public void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                UserCreateStatus userstatus = UserCreateStatus.AddUser;
                UserInfo NewUser = new UserInfo();

                NewUser.FirstName = txtFirstname.Text;
                NewUser.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
                NewUser.Username = txtUserName.Text;
                NewUser.DisplayName = txtUserName.Text;
                NewUser.Profile.City = txtCity.Text;
                NewUser.Profile.Country = "United States";
                NewUser.Email = txtEmail.Text;
                NewUser.Username = txtUserName.Text;
                NewUser.Membership.Password = txtPassword.Text;
                if (PortalSettings.UserRegistration != Convert.ToInt32(DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.PortalRegistrationType.PublicRegistration))
                {
                    NewUser.Membership.Approved = true;
                }
                {
                    NewUser.Membership.Approved = false;
                }

                UserCreateStatus userstatsus = UserController.CreateUser(ref NewUser);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: your link says "You Do Not Have Permission To View The Requested File"

Comment: It may not be the Exact answer, but, it tells me where I need to be and gave me a good overview of the provider. What I will use, is use the dnn membership provider and create my own page referencing that. This way, I can cutomize registration anywhere, and i do not have to rewrite the provider.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the `NewUser.PortalId`.
This can be set to `NewUser.PortalId = PortalId;`

Comment: I only use one portal in each deployment dnn is slow enough, but I would assume you would need that in a multi portal environment.